# List function, how to get an average of scores for each name- c# console application

Tags: c#, list, console-application, average

I have a list function on a console application on C#. This list function has different items where they look something like `'matt,5' 'matt,7' 'jack,4' 'jack,8'` etc...

I want to be able to combine all of the names where I only see their name written once but the number after them are averaged out so it would be like `'jack,5+7/2'` which would then display as `'jack,6'`.

So far I have this...

```
currentFileReader = new StreamReader(file);
List<string> AverageList = new List<string>();
while (!currentFileReader.EndOfStream)
{
    string text = currentFileReader.ReadLine();
    AverageList.Add(text.ToString());
}
AverageList.GroupBy(n => n).Any(c => c.Count() > 1);
```

Not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: Might make your life easier if you had some kind of data model to store this information in instead of having to work with just List<string>.

Comment: please show all relevant code as well as look at the Faq on how to ask a question.. this is a rather poorly formatted question..

Comment: Give this guy a break, So many downvotes for not such a bad question

Comment: Personally I don't downvote questions by new users that are valid but perhaps not well-asked in terms of what the SO community is used to.  Instead, I explain what they did wrong and point them to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  There's no reason to close this question for being "unclear", as there is a valid answer directly on point.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is to `Split` your each string item on `,` and then group by first element of the returned array and average second element of the array *(after parsing it to `int`)* something like:

```
List<string> AverageList = new List<string> { "matt,5", "matt,7", "jack,4", "jack,8" };
var query = AverageList.Select(s => s.Split(','))
    .GroupBy(sp => sp[0])
    .Select(grp =>
        new
        {
            Name = grp.Key,
            Avg = grp.Average(t=> int.Parse(t[1])),
        });
foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Avg: {1}", item.Name, item.Avg);
}
```

and it will give you:

```
Name: matt, Avg: 6
Name: jack, Avg: 6
```

**But,** a better option would be to use a class with `Name` and `Score` properties instead of comma separated string values.

*(The code above doesn't check for invalid input values)*.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will want to populate your unformatted data into a List, as you can see I called it rawScores. You could then Split each line by the comma delimiting them. You can then check to see if an existing person is in your Dictionary and add his score to it, or if not create a new person.

After that you would simply have to generate the Average of the List.

Hope this helps!

```
var scores = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>(); 
                var rawScores = new List<string>();
                rawScores.ForEach(raw =>
                {
                    var split = raw.Split(',');
                    if (scores.Keys.All(a => a != split[0]))
                    {
                        scores.Add(split[0], new List<int> {Convert.ToInt32(split[1])});
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var existing = scores.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Key == split[0]);
                        existing.Value.Add(Convert.ToInt32(split[1]));
                    }
                });
```